# How much we can trust compiler optimization?

Tags: c++, optimization, compiler-optimization

I wrote following code to calculate intersecting points of two circles. The code is simple and fast enough. Not that I need more optimization, but I can think of optimizing this code more aggressively. For example `h/d` and `1.0/d` are calculated twice (Let's forget about compiler optimizations).

```
const std::array<point,2> intersect(const circle& a, 
                                         const circle& b) {
    std::array<point,2> intersect_points;
    const float d2 = squared_distance(a.center, b.center);
    const float d = std::sqrt(d2);
    const float r12 = std::pow(a.radious, 2);
    const float r22 = std::pow(b.radious, 2);
    const float l = (r12 - r22 + d2) / (2*d);
    const float h = std::sqrt(r12 - std::pow(l,2));
    const float termx1 = (1.0/d) * (b.center.x - a.center.x) + a.center.x;
    const float termx2 = (h/d)*(b.center.y - a.center.y);
    const float termy1 = (1.0/d) * (b.center.y - a.center.y) + a.center.y;
    const float termy2 = (h/d)*(b.center.x - a.center.x);
    intersect_points[0].x = termx1 + termx2;
    intersect_points[0].y = termy1 - termy2;
    intersect_points[1].x = termx1 - termx2;
    intersect_points[1].y = termy1 + termy2;
    return intersect_points;
}
```

My question is how much we can trust C++ compilers (g++ here) to understand the code and optimize final binary? Can g++ avoid doing `1.0/d` twice? More precisely I want to know where is the line. When we should leave fine tuning to compiler and when do we do optimization?

Comment: The standard says very little about optimizations. It depends on the compiler and the flags you provide. You can use https://godbolt.org/ to see what a given compiler outputs.

Comment: I will say, don't rely on the compiler optimizing `std::pow(x, 2)` to `x * x`. That change could yield significant improvements.

Comment: As far as *trust* goes, I trust my compiler to produce correct results until I have proof that it isn't. If the output is unexpected, I will immediately assume that it's human error, not a compiler bug.

Comment: I have no trust.  I do have a profiler though.

Comment: thats not how you spell radius

Comment: [*This*](http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/329124/2429) might be relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Popular compilers are pretty good in optimization nowadays.
It is very likely that the optimizer detects common expressions like `1.0/d`, so don't care about this one.
It is much less likely that the optimizer replaces `std:pow( x, 2 )` by `x * x`.
This depends of the exact function you use, the compiler version you are using and the optimization command line switches. So in this case, you're better off to write `x * x`.
It's hard to say how far an optimizer can go and when you as a human must take over, this depends on how "smart" the optimizer is. But as a rule of thumb, the compiler can ony optimize things it can deduct from the lines of code.
Example:
The compiler will know, that this term is always false: `1 == 2`
But it can't know that this is always false as well: `1 == nextPrimeAfter(1)`, because therefore it would have to have knowledge about what the function `nextPrimeAfter()` does.